# Why can't I run my pdfTEX?

Tags: pdftex

I am trying to typeset my file, but I don't get the PDF version. Instead I get this error message:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./LatexThesis.tex
LaTeX2e <2015/01/01>
Babel <3.9l> and hyphenation patterns for 79 languages loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(./LatexThesis.aux) (./LatexThesis.aux) )
No pages of output.
Transcript written on LatexThesis.log.
```

Comment: Please give `\end{document}` after your text. Please post your `Latexthesis.tex` file.

Answer (score 4):

There is no error message shown in your question. That is a normal error-free log, from a document that presumably looks like this

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Which may not be the intended document, but check exactly what is in the file

```
./LatexThesis.tex
```

Note that you are using LaTeX2e <2015/01/01> there have been 5 releases since then, you may want to update your system with `tlmgr update`.